# C# Web Application - Depressed Button Appearance

Tags: c#, web-applications, button

I'm trying to implement something like the following graphic below; where the user has 3 possible options, and the current option looks like a depressed button.

[image: Button Mockup]

Everything I've found so far wants me to use a CheckBox with the appearance property set; but that is for windows forms, and not a web application.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Send the depressed button to the psychiatrist :)

Comment: @Denis Biondic - now that was funny.

Comment: Unfortunately, all the Prozac around here is being consumed by the developers, leaving the buttons out of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a web application you can replace the buttons image with another image (that of a depressed button), or enable / disable the button to give the effect that it has been pressed.
We need more info or sample code of what you have tried or what you want to try.  For instance, are you dealing with image buttons?

Comment: This is still very much in the proof of concept phase.  There hasn't been any determination made of whether we're using HTML buttons, ImageButtons, etc.  I was thinking that if there isn't a straight-forward way of doing this, I'd just replace it with a drop down list or something similar.  The last thing we want to be doing here is spending a day or so wiring up something "pretty" at the expense of actual functionality.

Comment: @Jim B - Either way this is all very simple especially with asp.net.  You could use ImageButtons, regular buttons, hyperlinks, tab strip controls, etc.  Possibilities are endless.  I think you should worry more about rolling out that proof of concept then this, this point is very minor and if you want I can post sample code of how to enable / disable a button (although you probably can figure that out yourself).  You can also change the ImageUrl dynamically at the click of a button for ImageButton's.

Answer (score 1):

Plain old html with CSS.... one with `border-style: 1px outset black;` for unselected state and another one `border-style: 1px inset black;` for selected state. That way you avoid the use of custom images that are usually heavier. To control state, add a query string parameter that specifies which button is selected.

Then is just matter of setting the appropiate CSS class. No images, no extra load, just HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I would use custom images for this (and not HTML buttons).

Have two images for each button: pressed and unpressed. And keep track of the state so you can show the appropriate one. Or better yet, wrap the buttons in a simple web control.